# Problem organising Harvard bibliography

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib, harvard-style

Please help! My thesis bibliography is formatted in a modified Harvard-esque style (natbib). My examiners have requested that multiple papers by the same first author are cited in date order, but I can't find a way to make this happen.

Does anyone know of a field code I can add to the .sty file that will work?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you provided a bit more information about your TeX setup and, in particular, the bibliography style file (with filename extension `.bst`) you use. Please also confirm that you use the `natbib` rather than the `harvard` citation package -- the title of your posting is a bit ambiguous in this regard. A separate issue: I assume you've already done so, but do verify that your university really is requiring you to use this rather unusual sorting scheme.

Comment: Is biblatex an option for you??

Answer (score 1):

As Mico pointed out, it's not entirely clear what you want to achieve exactly but maybe something along the lines of

```
\usepackage[sorting=nyt,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

is already what you need. Biblatex is relatively drop-in. Just put your `\bibliography{...}` in the preamble and `\printbibliography` where the thing should ultimately go in the document.

Personally I use

```
\usepackage[natbib=true,sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=12,maxnames=2]{biblatex}
```

in my thesis BTW. Especially the `maxnames` option might need some tweaking according to your field. [texdoc biblatex](ftp://www.ctan.org/ctan/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) is also quite comprehensive in this regard.